# Zend appendFIle tweaking

Tags: function, zend-framework, tweak

How can I include a same .js file multiple times but it will add it to the header only once. The idea is similar to include and include_once function in PHP. I am using the following zend framework function. And idea would be appreciated.

```
appendFile($src, $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Extend Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript and loop through the container (`$view->headScript()->getContainer()`) to check whether the file already exists
2. Before rendering the headScript(), retrieve the container and filter out duplicates.